# Generate-if statement could not evaluate to a constant value

Tags: verilog, vivado

I was trying to generate a mesh of routers (each router is a module) of variable length which can be specified using two parameters. while the number of i/o ports are fixed for the module, the connections are internally generated and connected appropriately to the i/o. I have successfully generated all the ports, but could not generate the routers. Verilog compiler threw the error:

> conditional expression could not be resolved to a constant

The error was with the generation of routers. the expressions in the two for loops could not be evaluated and hence, the conditionals. I tried putting everything in an always block but no luck.

here is the code:

```
 `timescale 1ns / 1ps
 `define n ((i-1)*NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS + j)

module top_n_router #(parameter NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_ROWS = 2, NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS = 2)(
input clk, clr,
input [7:0] current_address_r1, current_address_r2, current_address_r3, current_address_r4,
input [31:0] data_in_core_r1, data_in_core_r2, data_in_core_r3, data_in_core_r4,
input full_in_core_vc1_r1, full_in_core_vc2_r1, full_in_core_vc3_r1, full_in_core_vc4_r1,
input full_in_core_vc1_r2, full_in_core_vc2_r2, full_in_core_vc3_r2, full_in_core_vc4_r2,
input full_in_core_vc1_r3, full_in_core_vc2_r3, full_in_core_vc3_r3, full_in_core_vc4_r3,
input full_in_core_vc1_r4, full_in_core_vc2_r4, full_in_core_vc3_r4, full_in_core_vc4_r4,


output reset,
output [31:0] data_out_core_r1, data_out_core_r2, data_out_core_r3, data_out_core_r4,
output full_out_core_vc1_r1, full_out_core_vc2_r1, full_out_core_vc3_r1, full_out_core_vc4_r1,
output full_out_core_vc1_r2, full_out_core_vc2_r2, full_out_core_vc3_r2, full_out_core_vc4_r2,
output full_out_core_vc1_r3, full_out_core_vc2_r3, full_out_core_vc3_r3, full_out_core_vc4_r3,
output full_out_core_vc1_r4, full_out_core_vc2_r4, full_out_core_vc3_r4, full_out_core_vc4_r4
);

localparam NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS = NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_ROWS * NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS;

wire gnd;
wire vdd;
assign gnd=0;
assign vdd=1;

genvar i,j,k,n;

generate
    for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)       // input [31:0] data_in_core_r1; to replace such ports
        begin  : r_dinc
               wire [31:0]data_in_core;
        end
    for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)       // output [31:0] data_out_core_r1; to replace such ports
        begin  : r_doutc
               wire [31:0]data_out_core;
        end
    for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)       // input [7:0] current_address_r1; to replace such ports
        begin  : r_addr
               wire [31:0]router_addr;
        end
    for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)       // wire data_out_link3_r1; to replace such ports
        begin  : r_dout
            for(j=1; j<=4; j=j+1)
                begin : link
                    wire [31:0]data_out_r_link;
                end
        end
     for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)      // input full_in_core_vc1_r1; to replace such ports
        begin  : r_full_i
            for(j=1; j<=4; j=j+1)
                begin : vc
                    wire [31:0] full_in_r_vc = 32'd0;
                end
        end
      for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)         // output full_out_core_vc1_r4; to replace such ports
          begin  : r_full_oc
            for(j=1; j<=4; j=j+1)
                 begin : vc
                      wire [31:0] full_o_r_vc ;
                 end
          end 
        for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTERS; i=i+1)       // wire full_out_link1_vc1_r1; to replace such ports
                   begin  : r_full_ol
                     for(j=1; j<=4; j=j+1)
                          begin : vc
                            for(k=0; k<=4; k=k+1)
                                begin : link
                                    wire [31:0] full_o_r_vc_l;
                                end
                          end
                   end
endgenerate

// Rn = (i-1)*NUMBER_OF_COLS + j ie, numbering of nth router is given by this relation

generate           
        for(i=1; i<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_ROWS; i=i+1)
            begin : r_row
                if (i==1) 
                    begin
                        for(j=1; j<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS; j=j+1)
                            begin : r_col                      
                                if (j==1) 
                                    begin
                                        //instantiate here for top-left corner

                                    end     
                                else if (j == NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS)
                                    begin
                                        //instantiate here for top-right corner 

                                    end
                                else
                                    begin
                                        //instantiate here for upper-most edge

                                    end  
                         end
                  end     
                else if (i == NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_ROWS)
                    begin
                        begin
                            for(j=1; j<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS; j=j+1)
                                begin : r_col
                                    if (j==1) 
                                        begin
                                            //instantiate here for bottom-left corner

                                        end     
                                    else if (j == NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS)
                                        begin
                                           //instantiate here for bottom-right corner 

                                        end
                                    else
                                        begin
                                          //instantiate here for lower-most edge

                                        end  
                                end 
                    end
                end

                else
                    begin
                        begin
                            for(j=1; j<=NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS; j=j+1)
                                begin : r_col
                                    if (j==1) 
                                        begin
                                            //instantiate here for leftmost edge routers

                                        end     
                                    else if (j == NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS)
                                        begin
                                           //instantiate here for rightmost edge routers

                                        end
                                    else
                                        begin
                                           //instantiate here for central routers

                                        end  
                           end 
                    end

               end
         end 
endgenerate

    endmodule
```

I was using Vivado 2018.1 for writing this code. It doesn't complain of any syntax error but throws error while simulation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How did you simulate this? there is no test bench. Not sure if this makes any difference, but you have   extra `begin`..`end` blocks in the last 2 `else` clauses.

Comment: What is the line number that generates the error?

Comment: @Oldfart in the second generate block, the expression in the two for loops (nested ones with i and j) could not be evaluated to a constant.

Comment: @Serge I have not used a test bench. I just clicked "run simulation" in vivado. it used to open a blank window without errors but now, it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. apparently, the macro was not working properly (don't know why) and the text 'n' was not getting replaced. so, due to the undefined symbol, the expressions within the for loop could not be evaluated. Just replaced all the instances of `n` with `((i-1)*NUMBER_OF_ROUTER_COLS + j)` and it worked like charm.

Still, can anyone explain why didn't the macro work ?

EDIT:
Thanks to @Oldfart . The space around '+' was causing the problem.

Comment: Because there is a space in it?

Comment: @Oldfart No, there should be a space between the macro text and its value.

Comment: I mean the spaces around the '+'